What does this query means in Apache Superset?
Im doing a porting from dremio to mssql in a superset docker and i found this query into a chart (used like a drilltrought )
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        "@superset.template_dettaglio_cig"

is this used like a query on a chart ?
